# Unable to display logged in username in form

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a that is logged in by the session user name and I can only get it to show me the list of users and not the specific user that is logged in

The field name in the database is real_name

Here is what I have got so far;

```
<select name="complain_form" class="custom-select">
<option value="" disabled selected>Reported by...</option>
<?php foreach ($all_account_info as $account_info) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $account_info['id']; ?>">
<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['real_name'])){echo $selectedreal_name;}?></option><?php } ?>
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['real_name'])` is either true for _all_ users you are looping over there, or none.

Comment: Not really clear what you are even asking here - you want to display the name of the logged-in user as an option inside the select? Then _how_ do you want to distinguish it from all the other user names you are generating options for at the same time? Do you want to mark it by some additional prefix or suffix in the option text? Or are you actually asking how to _pre-select_ that option perhaps?